# Cannot load Cordova config(in IONIC)

Tags: ionic4

this is the error I get when I try to build my ionic project.
Error :  Cannot load empty config.xml file
i didnt change any config.XML file

Comment: Is there any code involved you could share?

Comment: yes,I had backup of my code but still i don't understand why my config.XML seems blank file.